# Grails Scaffold hide table column

Tags: grails, hide, scaffold

How I can hide `password` column from GORM view: 
[image]

My domain class:

```
class SecUser {
    static scaffold = true

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password


    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired



    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {

        username blank: false, unique: true
        password (display:false, blank: false)



    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
        SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
 }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
        // password = password
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `static scaffold = true` in a domain class?

Comment: It was in one of example. If I remove it, it doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: I wouldn't expect removing it would resolve the problem. Normally that property would be meaningless in a domain class unless you have code in your app (or in a plugin that your app is using) which does something with that property.  I think the default scaffolding plugin recognizes that property in controllers.

Answer (score 2):

The `display: false` constraint is used to hide the property from the default scaffolded view.  The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/scaffolddisplay demonstrates this.  You must have something in your app that is getting in the way of that.  Possibly you have generated views which contain the property.  Possibly you are using a plugin which is providing the view.